# Assigning Value to dynamic property causes a crash

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

This is the as to what I am trying to implement in this program

```
@interface settings : CBLModel

@property (copy) NSString* foo;

- (instancetype) initInDatabase: (CBLDatabase*)database withAllValues:(NSDictionary*)gameDic ChannelId:(NSString*)chann_id;
```

In .m file I am using this...

```
@implementation settings
@dynamic foo;

- (instancetype) initInDatabase: (CBLDatabase*)database
                  withAllValues: (NSDictionary*)gameDic ChannelId:(NSString*)chann_id
{
    NSParameterAssert(gameDic);
    self = [super initWithNewDocumentInDatabase: database];
    if (self) {
        self.foo=@"value";//this is where it crashes
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setfoo:(NSString *)foo{
  foo=[foo copy];//tried doin this but the value is not assigned

}
```

I am trying to set value of a dynamic property which results in the crash.. I need to use dynamic as I want to reflect it on server and using synthesize doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your property is in lowercase `foo`, and the dynamic declaration
in uppercase `Foo`. This could be a cause for problems. But assuming that this
was just a typo,

```
@dynamic foo;
```

tells the compiler that it should *not* synthesize getter and setter methods for the property.
It is a "promise" that the required accessor methods will somehow be provided at runtime.
Since you don't provide a setter method,

```
self.foo = @"abc";
```

must crash at runtime.

So unless you have a definite reason, you can just remove the `@dynamic` declaration,
and the compiler will synthesize getter, setter, and instance variable, if necessary.

A better answer might be possible if you explain what you are trying to achieve.

*Remark:* If your custom `setFoo:` goes into an infinite loop then you probably use the 
property setter inside the setter method, instead of accessing the instance variable directly.
A simple example:

```
-(void)setFoo:(NSString *)foo
{
    // wrong: self.foo = [foo copy];
    _foo = [foo copy];
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** The above answer was written before I knew that "settings" is a subclass of 
"CBLModel" from "Couchbase Lite". I do not have experience with that framework, but from
reading the [documentation](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/cbl-ios/#developing-apps) it seems to me that `@dynamic foo;` is indeed correct in this case,
and `setFoo:` should *not* be implemented in the subclass, because
the Couchbase framework creates the necessary accessor methods at runtime.

The only possible error *I* can see is that the custom initializer should call

```
self = [self initWithNewDocumentInDatabase: database];
```

instead of

```
self = [super initWithNewDocumentInDatabase: database];
```

Comment: I really do need to use Dynamic , but when I try setting the Value of_Foo=[foo copy];  it gives an error as undeclared identifier?????

Comment: @Geet: *You* have to declare the instance variable `_foo`. The compiler does not create that automatically for a dynamic property.

Comment: tried doing that to...so then sumthing like this happened...I declared
in .h file _foo and den in .m file @dynamic _foo.. 
and when i tried to set its property this is the method which it prompts
-(void)set_foo:(NSString*)_foo{
   //hence I tried doin this
_foo=[_foo copy];
}
..am really thankful to u for your time ..plz just help me out of this..

Comment: @Geet: It would be easier to help if you explain *why* you need a dynamic property.

Comment: I need to use Dynamic becoz I am actually passing thes values to my server , and if I use synthesize the value get set but are not reflected on the server, they get reflected only while using @dynamic..I had been using dynamic all this long but never encountered this problem before ..really dnt knw y this problem is coming now all of a sudden

Comment: *"if I use synthesize the value get set but are not reflected on the server"* - Sorry, but it is impossible to understand this problem with the code that you provided. What server? What kind of objects to you use, and how are values reflected on a server? Please add more information to your question. A small reproducible example would be perfect. - At minimum, show all your code related to "foo" in the superclass and in the subclass.

Comment: I posted the code above can u please check m still gratefull for all d help..thanks

Comment: @Geet: From your code I can see now that you are using Couchbase Lite (perhaps you should have mentioned that in the first place?). Unfortunately, I have never used that framework. From a quick look at the documentation, it seems that `@dynamic foo;` is indeed correct, and the Couchbase framework should create the accessor methods for you. I have one idea: Replace `super` by `self` in `[super initWithNewDocumentInDatabase: database];` .

Comment: didn't work man...the weird thing is this same thing works perfectly fine for one class and its causing problems in other...ne ways..thanks for the help

Comment: @Geet: I still think that `self = [self initWithNewDocumentInDatabase:...]` is the correct way to initialize the object (and you should *not* implement setFoo), but I don't have more ideas, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `@property(copy) NSString* foo;` with `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *foo;`

Answer (score 0):

`@dynamic` property indicates that implementation of setter and getter will be provided by some underlying code in runtime. It is commonly used in `NSManagedObject` subclasses of `Core Data`. There is no underlying code to manage your `@dynamic` properties if your object is a subclass of `NSObject`, so you are responsible for implementing setters and getters. Change `@dynamic` to `@synthesize` to let the compiler create appropriate setter and getter for you.

**UPD:** As of the latest compiler you may omit `@synthesize` as **Martin R** said.